# Circular import between models and helpers in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, signals

I'm trying to add a `post_save` Signal in my Django app and am running into a circular import issue.

`helpers.py`

```
from tracker.models import Record

def get_account_id(name):
    return name + '123'
```

`models.py`

```
from helpers import get_account_id


class Record(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    matched_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=False, blank=True)


def find_matched_account(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    instance.matched_account_id = get_account_id(instance.name)
    instance.save()


pre_save.connect(find_matched_account, sender=Record)
```

This is obviously a simplification but sums up the issue I'm running into. I could move the code in `helpers` into `models` but would prefer to store things like this in `helpers` because I'll end up using it in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Move the import into the function.

edit: submitted this a bit prematurely :P

When your imports are at the top of a file, they are executed as soon as *that* file is imported.  That causes this type of error.

You can limit your imports to a function's scope to avoid this issue.

When you run into this issue, you should at least double check that your architecture is really appropriate.  It is sometimes (but certainly not always) an indication that your architecture can be improved.

I find that you can usually move the function from the model to helpers, and make the first argument of the function be an instance of the model.  That way, you'll just have a helper importing a helper.

(second edit: removed example code, which made no sense)

Comment: The challenge is that I may import `Record` into a dozen functions in `helpers`. Is that an issue or just one of those things?

Comment: @kmomo apologies for the brevity of my initial response. I didn't mean to submit so quickly.  I've updated the answer with an example restructuring.  Generally, this problem can be solved by restructuring.  Occasionally, though, you'll simply need to move the import's scope.

Comment: Aaaand on second look, I've misread your question.  I would suggest moving the `find_matched_account` to helpers, though.